# function that finds specific values on a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

[this is image of my problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3IgF.png)

```
def print_values_of(dictionary, keys):
    for key in keys:
        print(dictionary[keys])


simpson_catch_phrases = {"lisa": "BAAAAAART!", "bart": "Eat My Shorts!", "marge": "Mmm~mmmmm", "homer": "d'oh", "maggie": " (Pacifier Suck)"}  

print_values_of(simpson_catch_phrases, 'lisa', 'bart', 'homer')
```

Comment: `dictionary[key]`

Answer (score 1):

You are looping the keys but not using the `key` variable. Try this:

```
def print_values_of(dictionary, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        print(dictionary[key])
```